# Powershell Match Filename with same basename but different file extensions and copy them to another folder

Tags: arrays

Powershell Version 2

Need some power shell help, Got a directory like the example below. Where there will be lots of files , the common property of them will be the name but with different extensions. I need to to recurse through the directory match any with the same base name and copy them to a location. The files need to be copied to the destination together.

Example of files. 40127.wav , 40127.txt , 40127.ini , 40128.wav , 40128.txt , 40128.ini

My example script Works but for only one member of the array. As i call the member of the array using $test[0] to match the basename. Not sure how to get it to go through the array as i seem to be breaking the foreach command.

$source = c:\audio

$test = Get-ChildItem -Path $source

foreach ($item in $test)

{get-childitem -path $source -recurse | where {$_.basename -eq $test[0].basename } | Move-Item -Destination C:\Backup }

Result
3 files in C:\backup 40127.wav , 40127.txt , 40127.ini .

Any help much appreciated.